# Picker control methods related to Focus

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, watchkit

I have a iOS + Watch app with a `UIPicker`, and I keep getting logs related to it that I can't figure out related to the Watch app:

> [default] -[SPRemoteInterface handlePlistDictionary:fromIdentifier:]:2977: ComF:->Plugin method .pickerFocus is not implemented by the controller (null)
>
> [default] -[SPRemoteInterface handlePlistDictionary:fromIdentifier:]:2977: ComF:->Plugin method .pickerClearFocus is not implemented by the controller (null)

I checked the documentation and the closest thing I could find was just the `pickerDidFocus()` method, which seems to be talking about general problem area I'm having, but *no clear implementation ideas for specifically `.pickerClearFocus` and `.pickerFocus`.*

Comment: For me it only happens on the simulator, so probably nothing to worry about?

Comment: @MaciejTrybiło good to know!

Comment: same thing happening to me when i am clicking on a button in table row in watch app &  button action method is also not calling..

Comment: @jayantrawat yup still happens to me

Comment: Everything I find seems to indicate it's a bug in Xcode or something, I guess it can be ignored.  I'm just curious has anyone had a problem (or success) submitting apps with this?

Comment: @Dan I submitted an app with it and it was approved

Comment: Same here but button action method is not calling so my button can't work properly, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did found a solution for my case (WKInterfaceButton). The button reference outlet and the button sent action outlet must be in the same class. The message is shown when selector outlet references to the view and the action references the view controller.

Cell :

```
class aCellView: NSObject {
  var delegate: WKInterfaceController? = nil

  // The action outlet
  @IBAction func doSomeThing() {
    self.delegate!.doSomeThing()
  }
}
```

Controller :

```
class HomeInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
  // ... where you implement your cell
  cell.delegate = self
  // ... where you implement your cell
}
```

Comment: Not the same for Pickers ?

Comment: Not *quite* the same exactly

Answer (score 2):

Same with ".pickerSettle" ...

"I'm having the same problem. Looks like a bug of the iOS or XCode, because the public API does not incude a method ".pickerSettle", and the existing method "pickerDidSettle" is actualy called just fine. Everything seems to be working as expected."

from:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/68971